# The value of $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{|x|}}$

Tags: analysis, limits

I want to find the value of
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{|x|}}.$$

Since $x \rightarrow + \infty$, I only consider the value of the function for $x \ge 0$, i.e.
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}}.$$

Noticing that the numerator and denominator both approaches $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches $+\infty$, I tried using L'Hôpital's Rule. However, it makes things worse. I did check at Wolfram Alpha, and found out that the value of the limit is $\infty$.

I then noticed that both the numerator and the denominator has powers of some function of $x$. Taking natural logarithm of the numerator and denominator, we have $$\dfrac{\ln e^{x^2}}{\ln 10^{x}}=\dfrac{x^2 \ln e}{x \ln 10}=\dfrac{x}{\ln 10}.$$

This seems really silly, but would I be justified if I say that $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}} = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{x}{\ln 10}= + \infty?$$

If this is incorrect, kindly give me a hint to tackle this problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: it is indeed infinity

Comment: How about writing $10^x = e^{x ln 10}$. Now, rewrite your fraction using exponent rule.

Comment: Also, just to point out that it is not true generally $\lim\frac{f}{g}$ and $\lim\frac{ln(f)}{ln(g)}$ are the same. A counterexample: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{2x}}{e^x} = \infty$, while taking the log of the numerator and denominator, we get $\lim 2x/x = 2$, which is not infinity.

Comment: @bonsoon In which cases does this work?

Comment: @user4167 See alex.jordan's argument below to see how to justify using ratio of the log's diverging to infinity implying the original ratio diverging to infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the natural logarithm of the fraction and use your idea.

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}}=e^{ \lim_{x\to +\infty} \ln\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}}}$$

A much simpler solution is to observe that $10 <e^3$ and hence

$$ \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}}> \dfrac{e^{x^2}}{e^{3x}}$$

---

**Added:** To clarify why I can interchange the exponential and the limit.

Since $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \ln\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}} = \infty$, for each $M>0$ there exists some $N>0$ so that $x>N$ implies $f(x) >\ln (M)$. Then for $x >N$ we have

$$e^{f(x)} >e^{\ln(M)} =M \,.$$

Thus, for each $M>0$ there exists some $N>0$ so that $x>N$ implies $e^{f(x)} >e^{\ln(M)} =M$. This shows that

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{ \ln\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}}} = \infty  \,.$$

Had $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ been finite, to show that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{f(x)}=e^{\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)}$$

you'd need to use the continuity of $e^x$ and the following Theorem, which can be typically found in all Calculus/Analysis textbooks:

**Theorem** If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=b$ and $g$ is continuous at $x=b$, then

$$\lim_{x \to a} g(f(x)) = g(b) \,.$$

This Theorem is used to prove that composition of continuous functions is continuous, and it typically be found just before that.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how you get the first equality? I know that ${f(x)}=e^{\ln f(x)}$, but I don't understand how the limit is included.

Comment: @user4167 $e^x$ is continuous, thus it can be interchanged with finite limits. One can also check that the exponential function can be interchnaged with infinite limits, it is what we understand when we write $e^{\infty}=\infty$ and $e^{-\infty}=0$.

Comment: So $\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{f(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)}$ because $e^x$ is continuous? I would appreciate if you could direct me to resources where I could read more about the interchangeability of finite limits. Thank you.

Comment: @user4167 In this case $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=\infty$ so all you need to show is that if $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=\infty$ then $\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{f(x)} =\infty$. In general, you either use this argument, or use the continuity of $e^{x}$ IF the limit is finite... The interchangeability of limits is basically what it means that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @user4167 Added few more details.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. In the second line of the added part, where $f(x) \gt \ln (M)$, is $f(x)$ equal to $\ln\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}}$ or $\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}}$?

Comment: @user4167 $f(x)= \ln\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{x}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $k=ln6$, then $10^x=e^{kx}$. The limit you want is $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}e^{x^2-kx}$. With this your limits can be easily calculated.

Comment: You probably mean $k=\ln(10)$...

Answer (score 1):

The original problem could be handled more directly, but to pick up after what you have done so far: If you have shown that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(f(x))}{\ln(g(x))}=\infty$, then you have shown that for any $M$, there is an $x_M$ such that for any $x>x_M$, that $$\ln(f(x))>M\cdot\ln(g(x))$$ This implies $$f(x)>g(x)^M$$ and that $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>g(x)^{M-1}$$ Now if $g(x)$ itself approaches $\infty$, then it suffices to settle for any $M>1$ and you have your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can note that the function $10^x$ is increasing less rapidly than $e^{x^2}$ so that the limit is absolutely $\infty$